# How to set the value of a string property when a button is pressed? (Not in bge)

Tags: python, scripting, properties

How can I set the value of a string property when a button is pressed?

Just to clarify I don't mean in the blender game engine I mean in "regular" scripting.

Answer (score 2):

A button is a representation of an Operator in a layout. Example operator code:

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        if ob is not None:
            ob.name = "Foo Bar"
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
```

You put your code to assign the new string value in the `execute()` method.

If you don't need any logic, but want to plainly assign to a context member, you may use the existing operators `bpy.ops.wm.context_set_*`:

```
import bpy

def draw_func(self, context):
    props = self.layout.operator("wm.context_set_string", text="Change object name")
    props.data_path = "object.name"
    props.value = "New Name"

bpy.types.OBJECT_PT_context_object.append(draw_func)
```

This code adds a button to the *Object* panel in the *Properties Editor* to change the context object's name property (which is a string).

Answer (score 0):

Blender uses operators to perform actions. See the [api documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/info_quickstart.html#example-operator) and the `Operator Simple` template (Text editor -> Header Menu -> Templates -> Python)

A button is added in the draw function of a subclass of [bpy.types.Panel](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.types.Panel.html?highlight=panel#module-bpy.types) via

```
layout.operator(bl_idname)
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem?